# Vector field is path-independent if and only if the integral of the vector field over every closed loop in its domain is zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation, vector-analysis, vector-fields

While trying to understand [the proof of the converse of the gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem#Converse_of_the_gradient_theorem) I have a hard time to understand why a vector field is path-independent if and only if the integral of the vector field over every closed loop in its domain is zero. Wikipedia says that should be "straight forward to show" but I don't get it.

---

Let's say $F$ is a path-independent vector field. How can we do anything with $\int_\gamma \langle F,dx \rangle$ since we don't know if it has a potential at all?
It would be easy if there would be a potential $\phi$ with property $\int_\gamma \langle F,dx \rangle = \phi(\gamma(a)) - \phi(\gamma(b))$. In this case we could easily conclude that every closed loop must be zero. But since $F$ is only a path-indpendent (the integral of $F$ over some piecewise-differentiable curve is dependent only on end points) vector field and not a gradient field this argument is invalid.

I was able to prove the converse statement though.

Where is the "straight forward"-part I'm missing?

Comment: It follows directly from the definition, doesn't it? (What _is_ your definition of a path-independent vector field?)

Comment: @TonyK I just added the definition .

Comment: Well, if your closed loop is piecewise differentiable, you can just shrink it to zero. So the integral of $F$ over the closed loop is $0$.

Comment: @TonyK What do you mean with "shrink it to zero"?

Comment: Make it shorter and shorter until it disappears. The integral around it remains unchanged, and the limit is obviously zero.

Comment: @TonyK Obviously. Thanks a lot!!